# Why does my website's 404 error page redirect to the homepage instead of showing the actual error message?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

My php website 404 page redirects to my homepage(whenever i type something wrong its directly take me to the homepage) .htaccess code below.

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```